# Django rest framework: searching on annotated field using ModelViewSet

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets, django-rest-framework-filters

how are you?   :)

My question is about using django RF ViewSets, RF Filters, over annotated fields with custom Object Managers.

So I've got this class

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):

    this_does_not_matter = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    objects = SomeClassManager()
```

with some manager with this shape

```
class SomeClassManager(models.Manager):

    def full_objs(self):
        qs = self.all()
        qs = qs.annotate(
            some_annotated_field=Count('this_dont_matter_either')
        )
        return qs
```

and finally, this viewSet

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
...

class SomeClassViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = SomeClass.objects.full_objs()
    serializer_class = SomeClassSerializer
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('some_annotated_field',)
```

and I get

> SomeClass has no field named 'some_annotated_field'

even though i **do** get that field when asking for it to the api.

Question is: how do I get to search on `some_annotated_field`

Comment: What is the relation between `SomeClass` and `Room`

Comment: @ishitasharma Please excuse me. I think (hope) now it's the correct scenery. Edits: `Room` was replaced by `SomeClass`, and the line `objects = SomeClassManager()` was added to SomeClass class.